# Prove that the composition is homeomorphic to a disjoint union

Tags: general-topology

How to prove that X × S is homeomorphic to the disjoint union of |S| copies of the space X, if X - some topological space, and let S - be a space with a discrete topology?

P.S I know that a subset of a disjoint union is called open if its intersection with each of the components is open. And also I actually know the definition of disjoint union. But still have no idea how to prove it based on this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: For some additional ideas on what you should add to your question, see our guidelines on how to [provide missing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960), and on how to [avoid "no-clue" question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). For example, have you written out the definition of the disjoint union topology and tried to work with it?

Comment: I know that a subset of a disjoint union is called open if its intersection with each of the components is open. And also I actually know the definition of disjoint union. But still have no idea how to prove it based on this

Comment: Do you have a map $X\times S\to \bigsqcup_sX_s$ in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Recap: The disjoint sum $\oplus_{s \in S} X_s$ of $|S|$ many copies of $X$, is the set of all pairs $\{(x,s): x \in X, s \in S\}$, where the $s$ coordinate serves to make the copies of $X$, $X \times \{s\}$, pairwise disjoint.

Note that *as a set* this is just $X \times S$. Denote its two projections as $\pi_S$ and $\pi_X$ resp.

The disjoint sum topology $\mathcal{T}_s$ is defined as

$$\{O \subseteq X \times S\mid \forall s \in S: \pi_X[(X \times \{s\}) \cap O] \text{ open in } X\}$$

while the product topology $\mathcal{T}_p$ is defined as the smallest topology such that $\pi_S$ and $\pi_X$ are continuous and which has as a base $$\mathcal{B}=\{O \times O'\mid O \text{ open in } X, O' \text{ open in } S\}$$

---

I'll now show that these topologies on $X \times S$ are actually identical.

Note that if $O$ is open in $X$, then $\pi^{-1}[O] = O \times S$ is open in $\mathcal{T}_s$, as for all $s$, $$\pi_X[(X \times \{s\}) \cap (O \times S)] = \pi_X[O \times \{s\}]= O$$

and if $O'$ is open in $S$, then $\pi_S^{-1}[O'] = X \times O'$ is open in $\mathcal{T}_s$ as

$$\forall s \in S: \pi_X[(X \times \{s\}) \cap (X \times O')]=\begin{cases}
X & s \in O'\\
\emptyset & s \notin O'
\end{cases}$$

and both sets are open in $X$. So both projections are open and hence $\mathcal{T}_p \subseteq \mathcal{T}_s$ by minimality.

Conversely, if $O \in \mathcal{T}_s$ and $(x,s) \in O$ then we know by definition
$O' := \pi_X[(X \times \{s\}) \cap O]$ is open in $X$ and $$(x,s) \in O' \times \{s\} \subseteq O$$

and $O' \times \{s\} \in \mathcal{B}$ (using that $\{s\}$ is open in $S$) and so $(x,s)$ is an interior point of $O$ for $\mathcal{T}_p$, and as $(x,s)$ was arbitrary, $O \in \mathcal{T}_p$ and so $\mathcal{T}_p \subseteq \mathcal{T}_s$ and we have equality of topologies.

Hence $X \times S \simeq \oplus_{s \in x} X_s$.